# DNN DAL 2 hydrate object and other

Tags: dotnetnuke

Using basic DAL 2 to grab data from a table that has tabid. Would like to also get the Tab Url through the DNN API. I could join to the Tabs table, but want to work with the api.

Here is my model.

```html
[TableName("My_Products")]
    [PrimaryKey("ProductId")]
    [Cacheable("My_Products_", CacheItemPriority.Normal, 20)]

    public class ProductInfo     
    {
        public ProductInfo()
        {
            Langs = new List<ProductLangInfo>();
        }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public int LineID { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public string Culture { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public string ProductShortDesc { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public int TabId { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public string ProductURL { get; set; } //GET THIS FROM API
        [ReadOnlyColumn]
        public List<ProductLangInfo> Langs { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Controller

```html
 public IEnumerable<ProductInfo> GetProducts(string language)
        {
            using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
            {
                string sqlCmd = ";WITH cte as (SELECT * FROM [ProductsLang] WHERE Culture = @0)" +
                                " SELECT Products.*,cte.ProductName, cte.ProductShortDesc, cte.TabId" +
                                " FROM [Products] as Products" +
                                " INNER JOIN cte ON Products.ProductId = cte.ProductId";

                string order = " ORDER BY Products.ProductId DESC";
                return ctx.ExecuteQuery<ProductInfo>(CommandType.Text, sqlCmd + order, language);
            }
        }
```

I guess my question is where is the best way to pass in the tabid from my query to the DNN API?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward using the NavigateURL method off DotNetNuke.Common.Globals

```
var url = DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId);
```

There are other ways to get URLs in DNN, but that is the easiest way that should respect all the various Providers that can be used to build out a URL

```
private string _productUrl = '';
public string ProductURL { get return DotnetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId);  }
```

Comment: So I should do this outside of my model and controller and call this from the front end? 
My module is an angular spa module, so I would create a webapi service to return this?

Comment: could you put it into the property itself? So that the call to "get" the URL, makes that API Call in the population of the object? Added some info to the answer, that's untested though

Comment: I thought that would work too, but it comes back as null. `
public class ProductLangInfo
    {
        public int? ProductsId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductShortDesc { get; set; }
        public int TabId { get; set; }
        private string _productUrl;   
        public string ProductURL   
        {
            get
            {
                return DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId);
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: If you step through that in Debug, can you see if TabID is populated when that call occurs?

Comment: I think maybe the way to do this is when the repository is populated.